# Odoo Api Externe

Tags: php, api, odoo, odoo-15

I'm trying to search in db odoo with api extern using php
So my first code is

---

```
$url = 'http://localhost:Port';

$url_auth = $url.'/xmlrpc/2/common';

$url_exec = $url.'/xmlrpc/2/object';

$username = 'username';

$password = 'password';

$db = 'dbname';

require_once('ripcord/ripcord.php');

$common = ripcord::client($url_auth);

$models = ripcord::client($url_exec);

$uid = $common->authenticate($db, $username, $password, array()); 

$customer_ids = $models->execute_kw( $db, $uid,$password,    

                                                    'project.project', 

                                                'search', 

                                                array( array('name', '=', 'Sanda') ) );
```

---

This code is working well
But I working to make a changes on it, I want that search it will be working on:
that the name is start with 's' for exemple and  I don't need more information about the rest of name How can  I do this
Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with search operator `=like` and the postgres wildcards `%` for any character or `_` for exactly one character.

So for your example "beginning with s" the domain would be `('name', '=like', 's%')`. The operator `=like` is search case-sensitive.

If you want to search case-insensitive use the operator `=ilike`: `('name', '=ilike', 's%')`.

[More about the operators and the search domains](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html?highlight=domain%20operator#reference-orm-domains)

Hint: Using `like` or `ilike` without the leading `=` will tell Odoo to surround the search term with `%` wildcards. Which for the "beginning with s" search could find more and not wanted search results.

Comment: odoo has `like` and `=like`. Former adds `%`  to the keyword. `s%` becomes `%s%%`

Comment: Yes i will correct that in my answer.